# Legal Database Column Names

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, postgresql, informix

I am designing a table that is to be used on multiple database engines:

- Informix SE
- Oracle
- PostgreSQL

Do all these databases allow numbers in the column names?  E.g. field1, field2, field3...

Comment: Thanks Denis.  If you post this as an answer, it will allow me to accept it.  Also, if you can link to some offical sites confirming this, it will be very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they do. (You can google for "identifier" for the gory details.)